# LISP - Fast output of byte array

Tags: output, character, common-lisp, cons

I am making a compiler for a language in LISP, and the overall aim is for the compiler to produce LISP code from the original language. Trying to measure the performance of the generated code, I found that it is severely lacking in printing strings.

In the original language, characters are byte -arithmetic- values, thus strings are arrays of bytes, and the value of the byte corresponds to the character whose value is the ascii-code of the byte. A "printable" byte array must be null-terminated. Thus, to print a byte array as a character string, I have to map the original array's elements into characters before printing it. The function that handles this is as follows:

```
(defun writeString (X &AUX (NPOS 0) (i 0))
  (declare (type (simple-VECTOR fixnum *) x))
  (declare (type fixnum NPOS i))
  (SETF NPOS (POSITION 0 X))
  (IF (NOT NPOS)
    (SETF NPOS (LENGTH X)))
  (princ (MAKE-ARRAY NPOS
                     :INITIAL-CONTENTS (map 'vector
                                            #'code-char
                                            (SUBSEQ X 0 NPOS))
                     :ELEMENT-TYPE 'base-char)))
```

and it is injected into the generated code.

Running a sample code with `time`, I found out that the `princ` part results in a lot of consing during execution, which slows things down. When in the place of `make-array...` a static string is put, there is no slowdown and no consing, so I guess that's the part the damage is done.

While compiling, I have set flags full on speed, the byte values are declared as fixnum for now in the generated code.

Can anyone point me to a better way to print my byte array as character string while avoiding excessive consing?

I could store bytes as characters from the get-go, but that would result in the parts of the language that treat them as numbers being slower due to the need to convert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problems in your code**

Your code:

```
(defun writeString (X &AUX (NPOS 0) (i 0))
  (declare (type (simple-VECTOR fixnum *) x))
  (declare (type fixnum NPOS i))
  (SETF NPOS (POSITION 0 X))
  (IF (NOT NPOS)
    (SETF NPOS (LENGTH X)))
  (princ (MAKE-ARRAY NPOS
                     :INITIAL-CONTENTS (map 'vector
                                            #'code-char
                                            (SUBSEQ X 0 NPOS))
                     :ELEMENT-TYPE 'base-char)))
```

There are a couple of mistakes in the code:

- `i` is not used
- the first type declaration is syntactical not valid
- the declaration for NPOS is wrong. You define it as FIXNUM, but it can be NIL.

There are a bunch of programming mistakes:

- there is no need to allocate any array if all you want is to output characters.
- even if you want to generate an array, one can do it once
- X is not a good name for a string

**A simple solution:**

```
(defun writestring (bytestring)
  (loop for byte across bytestring
        while (plusp byte)
        do (write-char (code-char byte))))
```

A type declared version could be:

```
(defun writestring (bytestring)
  (declare (vector bytestring))
  (loop for byte of-type (integer 0 255) across bytestring
        while (plusp byte)
        do (write-char (code-char byte))))
```

Instead `(integer 0 255)` one can also use `(unsigned-byte 8)`.

**About generating vectors:**

Let's also look how you try to create the array:

You create an array with make-array, using the contents from another array.
Why not tell MAP to generate the correct array?

```
CL-USER 46 > (map '(vector base-char) #'code-char #(102 111 111 98 97 114))
"foobar"
```

Now if you want to allocate arrays for some reason:

- do it once
- map the content into the generated array. Use `map-into` for that. It will stop with the shorter sequence.

Example:

```
CL-USER 48 > (let ((bytestring #(102 111 111 98 97 114 0 100 100 100)))
               (map-into (make-array (or (position 0 bytestring)
                                         (length bytestring))
                                     :element-type 'base-char)
                         #'code-char
                         bytestring))
"foobar"
```

Comment: Helpful remarks and simple solution! Thank you! May I ask what the first type delcaration should be like?

Comment: @NoobDoob well, you can't specify an element type for a simple-vector. The meaning of a simple vector is already that it is of element-type T. So it is just: `(declare (type simple-vector x))`

Comment: I see. The purpose of the declaration there is, or should be at least, to inform the compiler that the parameter is an array of fixnums. What would be the correct way to declare that?

Comment: The problem is that you can only do it in a very special sense: `(vector fixnum)` means vectors with upgraded element-type fixnum. It does not mean all kinds of vectors which contain only fixnums.  Thus: `(typep #(1 2 3) '(vector fixnum))` -> `NIL`

Answer (score 3):

You could rely on `write-sequence`, which hopefully is optimized to write a sequence of characters or bytes. It also accepts an `:end` argument which is useful for delimiting the end of the written string.

I doubt you really need to use literal vectors (which are always `simple-vector`), but if so you maybe want to change them. You can do it at read-time:

```
(let ((input #.(coerce #(102 111 111 98 97 114 0 100 100 100)
                       '(vector (mod 256)))))
  (write-sequence (map '(vector base-char)
                       #'code-char
                       input)
                  *standard-output*
                  :end (position 0 input)))
```

I never used something like the following, but you could also open the same file in both character and byte mode, and switch whenever necessary:

```
(with-open-file (out-c #P"/tmp/test"
                      :if-exists :supersede
                      :direction :output)
  (with-open-file (out-8 #P"/tmp/test"
                         :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)
                         :direction :output
                         :if-exists :append)
    (format out-c "Hello [")
    (file-position out-8 (file-position out-c))
    (write-sequence #(102 111 111 98 97 114) out-8)
    (file-position out-c (file-position out-8))
    (format out-c "]")))
```

It prints `"Hello [foobar]"` in /tmp/test, and it seems to work with multibyte characters, but you probably need to test that more.

Comment: I think the reason it works with multibyte characters is that lisp implementations typically implement `file-position` as a byte position because they work on byte-oriented systems and there isn’t really a sane thing they could do instead. This might be different if you have a different character encoding (eg maybe UTF-16 would work in two-byte positions) or are operating on a system that is not byte-oriented (I can’t really think of one which has a lisp, but a hypothetical lisp in js would be my closest guess).